# How do I install a package from Ubuntu Karmic onto Jaunty?

Tags: ubuntu, apt

I'd like to know if the following is easy/possible/recommended.

The version of Ubuntu I'm using (jaunty) has an out of date package that I need to upgrade: 
http://packages.ubuntu.com/jaunty/libapache2-mod-wsgi (it's at version 2.3).

A future version (karmic) has the new version: http://packages.ubuntu.com/karmic/libapache2-mod-wsgi (version 2.5)

Is it possible to use apt-get to install the new version in a way that will work? Or is it simpler to just install from source?

As I understand it, if I install from source, then I'll be responsible for keeping it up to date, and apt-get update/upgrade won't do anything.

If I add the karmic universe repository to my package sources, what will happen?  Will it affect any other installed packages or just the one I add?  Will apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi get the right version?  What happens if/when ubuntu update the jaunty package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use non-standard packages in Ubuntu. You have to take care of the dependency resolution yourself.

You can download the package from the link in your questions.http://packages.ubuntu.com/karmic/libapache2-mod-wsgi

After you download, you can install with sudo dpkg -i or gdebi the gui .deb installer.

You may have to download additional a packages to resolve dependencies.

Comment: This worked perfectly for mod_wsgi.  No dependencies have changed.  I guess I'll find out if updates work eventually.

Answer (score 1):

One uses "apt pinning" to do this. An example is given here http://osdir.com/ml/ubuntu-users/2009-06/msg00516.html, you'll have to review the man page and adjust this to your needs.