# karmic and jaunty compatibilty

Tags: ubuntu-9.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install a package from Ubuntu Karmic onto Jaunty?](https://serverfault.com/questions/66546/how-do-i-install-a-package-from-ubuntu-karmic-onto-jaunty)

are karmic packages compatible with jaunty?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is related to this one:
[How do I install a package from Ubuntu Karmic onto Jaunty?](https://serverfault.com/questions/66546/how-do-i-install-a-package-from-ubuntu-karmic-onto-jaunty)

Hope it helps.